# Ionic 2 check Internet connection

Tags: ionic-framework

I have installed the Cordova network plugin, but cannot seem to check network connection.

This is my code

```
import { Network } from 'ionic-native';

declare var navigator: any;
declare var Connection: any; 

this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   if(Network.connection === 'none') {
       let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
       title: "Internet Connection",
       subTitle:"Please Check Your Network connection",
       buttons: [{
          text: 'Ok',
          handler: () => {
              this.platform.exitApp();
             }
          }]
        });
      alert.present();
     }
  });
}
```

I get warning message

> Native: deviceready did not fire within 2000ms. This can happen when
>   plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from
>   plugins/ and reinstalling them.

How could i go about resolving the issue?

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this under platform ready. Once your app is up and running, try to disconnect and reconnect from\to internet. You should get the messages on your console.

```
let disconnectSub = Network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('you are offline');
});

let connectSub = Network.onConnect().subscribe(()=> {
  console.log('you are online');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I try this code.Its work only watch changes for network connection.How to display alert msg in when app open without internet.Disconnect network after App opened cannot called onConnect() / onDisconnect() Kindly Advice me

Comment: On app open, check for navigator.onLine, it will return boolean value true or false, based on network connectivity.

Comment: how you will identify if we have a valid internet connection or not, e.g. if you are connected to a wifi network which don't have internet connectivity. Then how you will determine if app is online or offline.

Comment: This solution can be used to track the changes in the network connection. Is there any other method to check connection status while initial loading of the app

Comment: @AthulRaj did you find a solution for this??

Comment: @sumitmehra yes

Comment: @AthulRaj Please share

Comment: @sumitmehra I've added it as an answer

Comment: oops sorry my bad. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I made use of the network import and ionic events to manage network disconnection and conection

```
 checkDisconnection() {
     const disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
     this.checkConnection();
     disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe();
     this.nav.push('ErrorsPage');
   });
 }
 checkConnection() {
  const connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
  this.checkDisconnection();
  connectSubscription.unsubscribe();
  this.nav.pop();
  });
 }
```

Works perfectly fine. Any more information you need please mention in comments

Answer (score 0):

Navigator.Online only returns a Boolean when the app is on the browser not the device or phone